# Nontrivial solutions for "homogenous" Lyapunov equation/ anticommutator equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, linear-control

I am trying to find non-trivial solutions for $AX+XA=0$, where $A$ and $X$ are real, symmetric square matrices. $A$ is given and positive definite. I want to solve for $X$, which should be positive definite or positive semi-definite. Obviously, $X=0$ solves this equation, but I want to find a solution $X\neq0$.

The equation $AX+XA+Q=0$ is known in as the continuous Lyapunov equation in control theory and there is a theorem on existence and uniqueness of solutions $X$ if $Q$ is positive definite. However, in my case $Q=0$, so the theorem does not apply to my problem.

Are there any results on the existence of non-trivial $X$ and/or how to find them?

Comment: What is matrix $B$? Should the equation you want to solve be $A\,X+X\,B=0$?

Comment: Almost certainly it is as the OP wrote it, since this is the Lyapunov equation. The B matrix may come in via Q as $Q = BB^T$ (as I recall). The solution to the differential form of that equation is the controllability grammian. The form $A^tX + XA = 0$ emerges from the Lyapunov function corresponding to asymptotic stability.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I meant $X$ instead of $B$. I corrected this above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the theorem does not apply when $Q=0$ because there is only the solution $X=0_n$ in $M_n$.

Proof. Let $(\lambda_i>0)_i$ be the spectrum of $A$. The eigenvalues of the linear function $f:X\in M_n\rightarrow AX+XA\in M_n$ are the $(\lambda_i+\lambda_j>0)_{i,j}$. Then $f$ is a bijection and the sole solution in $M_n$ is $0_n$.